# Three.js How to color a triangle with color ramp

Tags: three.js

Imagine you have a triangle with the next heights: 0 , 4, 7 
I have a ramp-color with the next values :
0: blue , 3 : green , 6:yellow , 9: red.

How can I to achieve this ? I have to create a texture first, haven't I ? 
(and the apply UV mapping)

Or ... Could I write a shader for this ?

(I dont want to create more geometry data, I must not)
Thanks.

Comment: You can add vertex colors to your triangle and let webgl do the interpolation on the surface of the triangle.

Comment: I'm using a color ramp, not a simple two colors (that, yes webgl interpolate). I have green.blue.yellow.red ramp. For my triangle 0,4,7  (heights) I'd have green until 3, blue from 3 to 6, and yellow form 6 to 7. Other cases'd have another color distribution.

Comment: Would like to help but dont understand your question. Try to describe your scene better. Maybe do a drawing or show a screenshot? What "heights" do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about this in two ways. Writing a shader - planing your mesh. The gradient, you need to generate yourself, either through code, or say photoshop. A tiny texture might be enough to create this pattern.

If you are generating your triangles somehow, then you need to generate some uvs. This can be as simple as mapping your vertex.xy or zy or even just y into your UV;

From here, applying a simple

```
 MeshBasicMaterial({map:yourGradientTexture});
```

will create your effect. Now you have to figure out how to generate these gradients and fit them in something like THREE.DataTexture(). On the flipside you don't touch shader code.

If you are writing the shader, a common way to do these ramps and tone mapping and such is to map some value normalize and read from a texture. This can be NdotL or anything. The most common way to access a texture is with uv so you get

```
texture2D(_yourSamplerTex, UV );
```

but you can do this, and you havent generated any extra data, you're just using your positions

```
varying vec3 myWorldposition; //or modelPos or screenPos or whatever
void main(){
    vec3 myColorGradient = texture2D( _myGradientSamplerTex, vec2(0.0, myWorldPosition.y)).xyz;//if your gradient is horizontal in the texture
```

Alternatively, a bunch of math and lerps ie. "mix()" in glsl could give you a procedural gradient, but it would be cumbersome, limited and probably complicated. Probably easier to generate this texture in JS and update it. Alternatively, you can use a planeMesh, color it's vertices, let them get interploated, render this to a tiny render texture, and map that instead.

Comment: thanks. Anyway would I have to rotate my triangle. ? For example: a1  [0.00 0.00 100.00] a2 [200.00 200.00 1.00] a3[ 201.00 201.00 150.00] is a singular triangle. I couldn't apply UV if I dont figure out the true dimension of this , do I ?

Comment: Well, it really depends what you are trying to achieve. You get the basic picture? Why don't you try accessing the uvs, and try making them 0|0, 0|1, 1|1 for example, see what you get. Then try with the position components. In the shader you could do all sorts of math, but without touching the code i think the only way to do this is via UVs. But the basic idea is to map the gradient 1 dimensionally basically, so it streches to infinity in two dimensions. This will give you the height...